# Serving Django-NGINX content from private subnet to AWS application Load Balancer

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, private-subnet

We have hosted Django application on NGINX in EC2 private subnet, we are not able to access it via AWS application load balancer end point. Below is the configuration file from location `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myserver.conf` 
We are getting `504 Gateway timeout` using port 80 in configuration file and `502 bad Gateway` using 443 in configuration file.

```
upstream my_server {
  #server 0.0.0.0:80;
  server unix:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/star.sock fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
    listen 443; # default_server
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
client_max_body_size 4G;

access_log /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/logs/nginx-error.log;


location /static/ {
   root   /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/;


}


location / {


proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;


include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/star.sock;

}   


# Error pages
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
        root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/;
   }
   location ^~ /(css|js) {
                    root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/;
           }

}

server {
    if ($host = 0.0.0.0) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
if ($host = 0.0.0.0) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

listen 443;
server_name 0.0.0.0;
return 404;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your config to something like that:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.localhost;

client_max_body_size 4G;

access_log /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/logs/nginx-error.log;


location /static/ {
   root   /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/;


}


location / {


proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;


include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/star.sock;

}   


# Error pages
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
        root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/;
}
location ^~ /(css|js) {
                 root /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/;
}

}
```

Please note that you have configured location and root directive inside that:

```
location /static/ {
   root   /home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/
```

Be sure that files located in the correct directory, because the result path to static will be `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/star/dashboard/static/static/`